# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Salesforce breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  4         10
Users destroyed                                  16          0
Users deleted                                   103          0
Users contacted                                   6          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           398      3,585
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              176        680
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        271      7,177
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              435      1,825
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               521      6,261
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               11     12,527
Tags merged                                       7          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             3          6
Tag synonyms created                              3          0
Tag highlight language set                        1          0
Revisions redacted                                3          0
Questions reopened                               44         14
Questions protected                               3         60
Questions migrated                                3          0
Questions merged                                  4          0
Questions flagged⁴                                9      1,282
Questions closed                                181      3,123
Question flags handled⁴                         357        934
Posts unlocked                                    0          3
Posts undeleted                                  12        323
Posts locked                                      5        121
Posts deleted⁵                                1,689      7,722
Posts bumped                                      0      8,718
Escalations to the CM team                        6          0
Comments undeleted                               16          0
Comments flagged                                 82      2,924
Comments deleted⁶                             3,383      5,155
Comment flags handled                           782      2,224
Answers flagged                                  84      4,220
Answer flags handled                          2,748      1,556
All comments on a post moved to chat             45          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...